# ArcMap lagging when I use the measure tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, performance, measurements

ArcMap is lagging when I click the measure tool, my data isn't particularly big (biggest .shp is ~150mb) and my PC is brand new. Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/17673-Measure-Tool-Issue-for-ArcGis-10

Comment: I'm tempted to write a question titled "ArcMap lagging when I use ArcMap"

Answer (score 4):

After you activate the Measure Tool, press the Space Bar to disable snapping. There should be no lag.

Comment: This is a handy trick, but to clarify: you need to *hold* the space bar down while using the Measure tool to temporarily disable snapping. Simply pressing it once will only disable it for a fraction of a second.

Comment: Alternatively, open the Snapping Tool bar and turn snapping off.